# Issue with Fancybox in modal mode

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Given this link within the FancyBox framework:

```
<a class="fancyBox" href="http://localhost/ccms/index.cfm?do=user.update" id="userLink">Update</a>
```

If I click this link physically, The FancyBox modal window pops up and displays the contents of the User Update page. The window is in modal mode and the only way to close the window is via the Close / X. Clicking outside of the modal does nothing. So far so good.

However, if I try and trigger the window like this:

```
$("#userLink").fancybox().trigger('click');
```

The User Update page pops up in a modal as required, BUT clicking outside the modal now triggers the close event and the window is closed.

Any ideas why this is happening???

Ultimately what I would like is for the modal's behaviour to be consistent. But if no solution can be found for this, is there not perhaps a way to override the click event causing the modal to close and disable it?

Thanks, anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the modal behavior when you call `fancybox()` like that. You're likely overwriting the settings you provided the other way when you call it in that fashion. So in order to retain your settings, do this:

```
$("#userLink").fancybox({modal:true}).trigger('click');
```

But I would recommend you try: `$("#userLink").click();` which will trigger the click event and should use your existing settings.

Comment: Great answer sholsinger - thanks!
The second approach you recommended worked perfectly. 

The first one however, removes the close 'X' functionality from the modal. I suspect there should be another parameter passed to enable this?

Comment: Yes, most likely this one: `showCloseButton: true` so in full: `$("#userLink").fancybox({modal:true, showCloseButton: true}).click();`

Comment: That didn't work. Odd- checked the API and it definitely is the right property.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the fancybox api

1. hideOnContentClick:false
2. hideOnOverlayClick:false

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Just add parent: "form:first" to .fancybox({ }); function.

example:

```
$(".various").fancybox({
                maxWidth: 800,
                maxHeight: 600,
                fitToView: false,
                width: '50%',
                height: '50%',
                autoSize: false,
                closeClick: false,
                openEffect: 'none',
                closeEffect: 'none',
                parent: "form:first"
            });
```